# Py/sqlite3 error: InterfaceError Error binding parameter 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, visual-studio-code, discord.py

I have been working on some `sqlite3` for my discord bots reaction roles. I am getting this error and I don't know how or why:

```py
Exception has occurred: InterfaceError
Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
  File "C:\Users\dvorn\Desktop\BOT code\FunModule.py", line 123, in on_raw_reaction_add
    cor.execute("""SELECT * FROM rectionRoles WHERE message = ? AND emoji1 = ?""", (payload.message_id, payload.emoji,))
  File "C:\Users\dvorn\Desktop\BOT code\Irantu_code_v1.3.py", line 20, in start_bot
```

And the code:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        cor = con.cursor()
        cor.execute("""SELECT * FROM rectionRoles WHERE message = ? AND emoji1 = ?""", (payload.message_id, payload.emoji,))
        result = cor.fetchone()
        print(result)
```

Comment: *Error binding parameter 1 - **probably unsupported type.***

Comment: yes i know but why is it giving me that?

Comment: are you sure you're passing the correct type?

Comment: i dont know, thats why i came here for help

Comment: How are we supposed to know what type is it supposed to be? Please think, you did setup the database, you did create the tables and you're not posting any info about the types. It's not really difficult to check what type is it supposed to be.

Comment: ok i have a .db file and i have no idea types? i do have 6 columns

Comment: Please call `PRAGMA table_info(rectionRoles)` and post the output.